# Is there a way to get any information on the battery life through adb in android

Tags: android, performance

I have a requirement wherein I need to have an idea on how to find the battery life of a battery for any android device. I tried the command -
./adb shell dumpsys battery and that gives a host of information . Can anyone tell me what the health parameter in this dumpsys output stand for. Is there anything in here that can help me map the information to the battery life ?

AC powered: false
  USB powered: true
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 100
  scale: 100
  voltage:4313
  temperature: 308
  technology: Li-ion

Comment: Based on what I found [here](http://tasker.wikidot.com/using-linux-shell-with-tasker-for-a-technical-battery-widget) the health status seems to be on a scale of of 2 to 5 with 2 being excellent health and 5 meaning the battery is not good.

Comment: Thanks , I did see the link u mentioned above but it looks like the 2-5 rating is more of an assumption of the author or is it the standard ? Slightly confused

Comment: To further on what A--C commented , this site gives slightly more details - http://android-test-tw.blogspot.com/2012/10/dumpsys-information-android-open-source.html

Answer (score 0):

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

So your battery life is given as "level" out of your "scale."

Comment: Thanks , this battery life indicates the current battery charge right ? Based on your earlier comment I assume the health status is the only way through software that we would get to know about the total battery life (how long the battery has been used in the phone / tablet )

Answer (score -1):

Instead of getting it with adb you can go to telephony then dial `*#*#4636#*#*` then go to battery information and it will give you all the information including health , temperature.